# PRISM: Use view-first approach or view-model first approach?

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism, region

I'm trying to implement this scenario. In a listbox, show me several modules and when the user selects a module, must load the controller.

[image]

I supposed that the controller must have `ModuleAContent`, `ModuleAContent2` and `ModuleAContent3` views and view models.

Generally I put the viewModels into the controller. But at this situation, I guess I need first-approach.

My doubt is, what should contain my Controller and should I use view-first approach?

Comment: Do you plan to have per each module one controller and three views/viewmodels? Or rather leave out the dedicated module-controller? And is each content control of your registered as a region?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the modules itself. In my opinion if the modules are coupled with completely independent datacontext and the showing of modules have absolutely no link with what the other modules did, it is just a matter of choice whether you use view-first or not. However, if it is not the case the the possibility of setting something in the view model in the controller will make viewmodel in controller approach easier.